# How to change Status when update form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working with Django form Updation, but I am facing a small issue, I have 3 fields in form updating, `name`, `image`, `status`, Now if a user upload a image in form then status should be change automaticly in my database.

here is my `forms.py` file...

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   model = Product
   fields = ['name', 'image', 'status']
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def myview(request, id):
  datas=Product.objects..get(pk=id)
  form = UpdateForm(instance=datas)
  if request.method === 'POST'
      form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=datas)
      if form.is_valid():
         edit = form.save(commit=False)
         edit.save()
         return HttpResponse('Success')
   else:
      return HttpResponse('Fail')
 template_name='test.html'
 context={'datas':datas}
 return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Default `status` is `0` in my database, If a user upload image then `status` should be `1` in my database, please let me guide how i can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to override the `save()` method of your form class. A possible implementation could be:

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(UpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # Set status if saving picture
        if instance.image:
            instance.status = 1

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return m
```

Comment: and what will be the code of my `views.py` file, would it be the save as i written

Comment: could you please write the complete code of `views.py` and `forms.py` file...

Comment: You should change anything in your view, just add this method to your form class definition.

Comment: And what I will do if I want to clear the previous image, and when I will clear the previous image then the status should be `0`

Comment: In the save method you override you can check for the presence or absence of the image and then set the status accordingly.

Comment: Please check my this question ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957780/how-to-change-another-field-value-when-clear-in-django