# How to change another field value when Clear in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working with Django form Updation, but I am facing a small issue, I have 3 fields in form updating, `name`, `image`, `status`, Now if a user uploads an image in the form then the `status` is automatically changing to `1` in the database.

but now if I clear the form using `checkbox` of the image then this `status` should be updated `0` in my database

here is my `forms.py` file...

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(UpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)

    # Set status if saving picture
    if instance.image:
        instance.status = 1

    if commit:
        instance.save()
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def myview(request, id):
    datas=Product.objects..get(pk=id)
    form = UpdateForm(instance=datas)
    if request.method === 'POST'
       form = UpdateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=datas)
       if form.is_valid():
         edit = form.save(commit=False)
         edit.save()
         return HttpResponse('Success')
    else:
      return HttpResponse('Fail')
    template_name='test.html'
    context={'datas':datas}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my `site.html` file...

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
<a href="/media/{{datas.image}}"/>{{datas.image}}</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="image-clear" id="image-clear_id"/> Clear
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

When I update this form then it updates `1` in the status field, but if I clear from `form` then `status` should be `0` in my database

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code by unchecking the checkbox, the following line will be skipped:

```py
if instance.image:
    instance.status = 1  # This will be skipped since instance.image is now False
```

Try adding an action for when the condition for instance.image is false.

```py
if instance.image:
    instance.status = 1
else:
    instance.status = 0
```

You can of course refactor that to write it more elegantly but that clearly shows the logic.

Comment: it's clearing the image from the database when I submit the form after clicking on the checkbox, but `status` not updating in my database. it's still `1`

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. When you save the form, you are saving to the model because of the `commit=True` row. You are then checking to see if an image exists, which it does not, therefore no change will be made to `instance.status`.You cannot assume that it will change back to `0` automatically.